# How to get id of commit after committing using JGit Library

Tags: java, jgit

I am using the below code to commit my changes.

```
CommitCommand commitCommand = git.commit();
commitCommand.setMessage("My change");
commitCommand.setAuthor(name, name + "@xyz.com");
commitCommand.call();
```

I want to know the commit id of this change. Because there can be a || process committing between the time I get the latest commit id and this particular commit. So to get the changes happening in this particular commit I need the commit id of the above commit. AFAIK CommitCommand does not have a getID() API.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `commitCommand.call()`?

Comment: @Progman I just saw it, it return a RevCommit which probably has my commit id. I will check.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be use [RevCommit](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/GetCommitMessage.java) like below snippet :

```
        //Run commit cmd with commit msg
    RevCommit revCommit = git.commit()
            .setMessage(commitMsg)
            .call();
    log.info("Commint ID " + revCommit.getId().getName());
```